# error: kubectl get pods -> couldn't get current server API group list |docker-desktop

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, minikube, docker-desktop

I've been building and destroying couple of terraform projects and then after couple of hours came to a weird error saying:

```
kubectl get pods
E0117 14:10:23.537699   21524 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.59.102:8443/api?t
E0117 14:10:33.558130   21524 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://192.168.59.102:8443/api?t
```

tried to check everything I can even restore and purge data on docker-desktop but it didn't help.

my .kube/config :

```
kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443       
  name: docker-desktop
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: C:\Users\dani0\.minikube\ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 14:04:24 IST        
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.28.0
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://192.168.59.102:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-desktop
  name: docker-desktop
- context:
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 14:04:24 IST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.28.0
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: C:\Users\dani0\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt
    client-key: C:\Users\dani0\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.key
```

Answer (score 2):

well I've fixed it by deleting the minikube cluster with "minikube delete" and then just "minikube start" and now it seems to work to me :)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible VPN connectivity

Answer (score 0):

I think it relates to your certificate file, If possible, please regenerate your certificate file by using OpenSSL command.